# Does Performance impacted while Performing DML operation on View in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

we have a table named "Employee" and View named "Employee_View". This view referenced only one table ("Employee") no join etc.,. Now i have a question, if we perform any DML operation (Insert/Update/delete) on the View has a performance impact in the Query execution than direct DML operation on the table.

Please clarify the same.

Comment: Are you asking if inserting to the the view has any performance difference compared to inserting directly to the table? Sounds pretty easy to test, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If your view is not materialized and is only a select on the table, then doing DML operations on the view should have the same performance as on the underlying table.  There may be a very, very small amount of overhead in mapping the view columns to the underlying table columns.

Views are compiled once, so if the view has expensive operations that are superfluous to the update, these operations might still have a performance impact.  For instance, if the view calls a user-defined function, then that function will (probably) be called regardless of whether or not it is used in the update (I'm not sure if SQL Server has some sort of execution time optimization to remove such references).  However, this is not specific to an `update`.  The same would be true if you just selected other columns from the view.